# Find a series solution for legendre equation in powers of $(x-1)$ for $(x-1) > 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a series solution for legendre in powers of $(x-1)$ for $(x-1) > 0$

A Legendre equation of order $\alpha$ is

$(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' + \alpha(\alpha +1)y$

So basically I have to find a series solution in powers of $x-1$

Previously, I was asked to determine the indicial equation for the point $x$.
That I manage to solve, by making a variable change $t = x-1$, I have establish the following

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_{n}(r+n)^2(t+1)^{r+n}$

So by substituting $n=0$, I got $r^2=0$ and hence $r_1 = 0,\ r_2=0$

How do I proceed on with the next part, which is the question at hand.

The hints given were:

1.)write $1+x=2+(x-1)$

2.)$x=1+(x-1)$

3.)change of variable $x-1 = t$

I'm really stuck and have no idea how to proceed, any help and insights given will be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the substitution $t=x-1$, then your series should have $t^n$, not $(t+1)^n$.

The coefficient on the sum for $y^{\prime\prime}$ is $$(1-x^2)=(1-x)(1+x) = (1-x)(2-(1-x)) = -2(x-1) -(x-1)^2.$$

So when you multiply the coefficient inside the sum and split it you get

$$(1-x^2)y^{\prime\prime}= (1-x^2)\sum = (-2(x-1) -(x-1)^2)\sum $$ $$= \sum -2n(n-1)a_n (x-1)^{n-1}+\sum -n(n-1)a_n(x-1)^{n}.$$

The manipulation keeps all the power series in terms of powers of $(x-1)$.  The 3rd hint does the same thing for the $y^{\prime}$ term.

Comment: Hmm, I got $t+1$ because I substitute all the $x$ to $t+1$. So is it by luck that I manage to get the right answer for the first part ? Or that the 2nd part of the question is unrelated to the first part ? Thank you for your answer by the way, it helped.

Comment: The series should not have been in terms of $x^n$, but $(x-1)^n$.  You do the substitution because $t$ is easier to write than $x-1$.  It wasn't an accident, because, at this point in the problem, it doesn't matter what symbol is in the parens.